# how to limit number of occorruencies of a column after every X lines in python with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

The current problem I've right now is that I've a dataframe with different itens and number of sellers and I need to limit the number of occorrencies a seller appears after every X lines (for example 40 (this would be a parameter)).
So i 've for example:

```
product     seller
banana      seller1
 kiwi       seller1
banana      seller2
kiwi        seller2
apple       seller2
peach       seller3
```

For example if I wanted to have a max of 2 products from one seller per 5 lines let's say, how I would rearrange it to the output be something like:

```
product     seller
banana      seller1
 kiwi       seller1
banana      seller2
kiwi        seller2
peach       seller3
apple       seller2
```

Comment: your example and output are the same. You just want it reordered?

Comment: yes, but based on the condition i told you, in every X lines, it needs to be the max amount of itens from a seller as i've described.

Comment: So, one seller per five lines in your example why is `apple, seller2` in the expected output? That's three different products from the same seller in four rows.

Comment: apple, seller2 is in line 6, if you look closer to the first 5 lines, the new order is just 2 itens from a seller in the limited space. because seller2 already had 2 products in the lines, i've changed position with the product from seller3.

Comment: Yes, but you still have three products from seller 2 within five rows of each other: "a max of 2 products from one seller per 5 lines." I am still a little confused on what you are looking to accomplish.

Comment: yes there's 2 products from seller 2 in the five 1st rows. the 3rd product is in row 6 (which would be a new count)

Comment: So the window is not rolling (1-5, 2-6, 3-7, etc.) but static - i.e., always rows 1-5, 6-10, 11-15, etc. Because if it was rolling then when you check rows 3-7 in your expected output there are three products from one seller.

Comment: I'm pretty confident there's a better solution if you want to detail why you need it this way

Comment: yes they're static